# JSON array foreach loop showing Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Tags: php, arrays, json

I want to display http://services.xyz.com/tours.asmx/Sample?type=2&CityID=1146&days=4 this array data in HTML.

Here is my code:

```
ini_set("display_errors", 1);

$url = "http://services.xyz.com/tours.asmx/Sample?type=2&CityID=1146&days=4";
$ch = curl_init($url); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, 1);
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields);        // set the fields to post 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);        // make sure we get the response back 
$xml = curl_exec($ch);      // execute the post 
curl_close($ch);                // close our session 

include "XMLParser.php";
$parser = new XMLParser();
$tour = $parser->parseString($xml);

print_r($tour);

//$errors = array_filter($tour);

if (empty($tour)) {
echo 'Error';
 }else{
  echo 'No Error';
 }

  //print_r($xml);
  //var_dump( $xml);
 //echo $xml;
    //$xmlfile = file_get_contents($tour);
    $ob= simplexml_load_string($tour);
    //$json  = json_encode($ob);
    $configData = json_decode($ob, true);

    foreach($configData as $result){
     echo '<tr>';
        echo '<td>'.$result->name.'</td>';
        echo '<td>'.$result->phone.'</td>';
        echo '<td>'.$result->email.'</td>';
      echo '</tr>';
    }
```

I am getting this error `Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:`

Please help me.
Thanks

Comment: The array is empty. Check it before looping

Comment: An image of code is not acceptable in a question. Put the actual code here

Comment: You probably want `json_decode` instead of `json_encode` since that API already gives you a JSON string. Get rid of line 24 and replace `$json` with `$ob` in your current line 25 (which will be the new line 24).

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) And the perfect question And how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) SO is **not a free Coding or Code Conversion or Debugging or Tutorial or Library Finding service** You also have to show that you have made some effort to solve your own problem.

Comment: @ccKep I did it and now getting this error  Warning: simplexml_load_string() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given in C:\xampp\htdocs\venga\test.php on line 23

Comment: @Akintunde I Check array is not empty I tried using print_r

Comment: I think you got confused along the way ... simplexml_load_string possibly does *not* what you think it does. `$tour` already is parsed, so you can't use it as a string ... you have to use the parser's functions to access the string content ... or use simplexml_load_string on `$xml`. see some examples for simplexml or the parser to see how you should do it ;o)

Comment: @Jakumi I did the same I use simplexml_load_string on $xml and I store all this in a variable and when I excute foreach loop I am getting nothing can you give it a try on your side and see if that works I really Appreciate your help

Comment: http://prntscr.com/guk3v9 this is how data I am getting now can you tell me how I can loop to get all record in HTML format ?

Comment: are you still getting the same error message? because that would be weird.since you gave `true` to `json_decode` as second parameter, everything now is an array. That means, you can't do `$result->key` but you have to `$result['key']`

Answer (score 0):

Here is my final Working code to help someone else who need this code.

```
<?php
ini_set("display_errors", 1);
//$days = "http://services.xyz.com/tours.asmx/Days?type=2&cityID=1146";
$url = "http://services.xyz.com/tours.asmx/Sample?type=2&CityID=1146&days=4";//Replace this with your own Web services Link
$ch = curl_init($url); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);        // make sure we get the response back 
$xml = curl_exec($ch);      // execute the post 
curl_close($ch);                // close our session 
$var = simplexml_load_string($xml);

$configData = json_decode($var, true);

/*echo '<pre>';
    print_r($configData);
    echo '</pre>';*/

foreach ($configData as $row) {
echo 'Day:' . $row['Day'].'<br>';
echo 'Time:' .$row['Time'].'<br>';
echo 'Description:' .$row['Description'].'<br>';
}?>
```